# Step in this proof unclear

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology

I have a question about the following proof that is given here: [Proofwiki](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Uncountable_Finite_Complement_Space_is_Not_First-Countable)

Why does the intersection of all $B_x$ only contain $\{x\}$? So how do I see that there is nothing else in this intersection? Does anybody of you know the exact argument?

Comment: For any $y\ne x$, the set $T\setminus\{y\}$ is open and contains $x$. This set contains some $B$. Then $y\notin B$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As David points out in the comments above, for any $y\in S$ with $y\ne x,$ we have that $S\setminus\{y\}$ is an open set (since its complement is finite) containing $x$. Since $\mathcal B_x$ is a neighborhood basis at $x$, then there is some $B\in\mathcal B_x$ such that $B\subseteq S\setminus\{y\},$ whence $y\notin B,$ and so $y\notin\bigcap\mathcal B_x.$